# python - Creating empty lists in dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda, empty-list

I have managed to create a list of zeros as dictionary values in the following way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
diction = defaultdict(lambda: list(np.zeros(len(8))))
```

The outcome of calling the above is an empty dictionary so calling `diction[0]` gives:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

which allows me to overwrite the zeros with any value or tupple that I want, but it does not allow me to append values.
So what I want to do is instead of having a list of zeros, I want to have 9 empty lists, so when calling `diction[0]` this is what the output should be:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []].
```

I know how to do this with for loops but I want a more efficient way, if possible with lambda.

Comment: The list would most likely be the most efficient. Definitely faster than lambda expressions. You should just use list comprehension `my_list = {i: [] for i in range(N)}`. That's the "python" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = {i: [[] for i in range(x)] for i in range(y)}
```

ForExample:

```
my_list = {i: [[] for i in range(8)] for i in range(10)}
```

**Output :**

```
{0: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
1: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
2: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
3: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
4: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
5: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
6: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
7: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
8: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
9: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]}
```